# Removing 'meta info' on Wordpress Custom Post Types (and blog posts) - CSS or PHP?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am wondering about the best way to remove/edit meta info from custom post types and blog posts in Wordpress.

Is it best to use CSS, or to make a change in a php file? (I have created a child theme, but I don't know PHP, so I'm reluctant to fiddle around with it).

On both standard posts, and on custom posts such as this one (https://www.violinschool.org/video/tuning-the-violin/), I am trying to:

a) remove the text 'posted on' and 'by', so that only the date appears. (first red annotation)

b) remove the text 'This entry was posted in Uncategorized. Bookmark the Permalink.', so that only the 'Edit' link for administrators (in the red square annotation) is left on the page.

Is there any way to make a fix with CSS so that I can avoid getting into PHP code I don't understand? Or is it crucial to do this change in PHP in the child theme?

Thank you very much!

[image]

Comment: it is all inside : `wp-content/themes/your_theme/single.php`

Comment: Probably better suited to http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not crucial to remove these options through PHP.  You can simply hide them with CSS if you are more comfortable.  However, if you want to get technical about responsible coding, then you should absolutely remove the code from PHP.

The reason being as whatever you are hiding from view is still being downloaded by the browser and placed on the page, and then hidden by CSS.  In this case, the text may not amount to much, but it is still KB being downloaded (think about foreign countries who pay per MB of data downloaded on their mobile data plan).  Not to mention a few extra lines of CSS to hide the code, which will also unnecessarily increase the size of the CSS file since you could have avoided writing those lines of code in the first place (again, extra KB downloaded). And then there is also adaptability to consider, as the code that is simply hidden from view on the page will still be picked up by a screen reader.

So... if you want to be responsible, you should learn a little PHP and do this the right way.  If you just don't care... hide the lines with CSS.

Comment: Thank you so much for this really helpful answer! :)